Discord.py Bot to exe file
So I've made a Discord Bot with discord.py and now I want to make it to an .exe file. I dont want to use pyinstaller/auto-py-to-exe since it does not protect my Code. Please don't say something like dont do it or something. I thought about this long and made this decision. So dont tell me something like: "The answer is that Python is not what you want and you will have better luck selling a service". I need just recommendations/experiences for obfuscators or compilers. So I can use pyinstaller.
Thanks for any help in the beginning!
I was trying to obfuscate it with pyob.oxyry.com but that just gave me errors.

You can generate a single file (.exe) with auto-py-to-exe, use the --one-file flag or in the GUI select One file.

This will probably not directly help you but will at least explain the errors you got: The page you mentioned only supports Python 3.3 - 3.7. Discord.py supports Python 3.8 upwards.

The site you provided doesn't necessarily obfuscate or protect your code. You see when the code is compiled variable names are already gone. Exe files only store op code for your system and architecture. Quick reverse engineering on the exe will result the same thing you see on the site you provided. Hiding code requires much more complex operations like encryption and salting. And don't forget there is no code that can't be reverse engineered. It's just harder as you add things on top.
So trying to do so is literally pointless I recommend sticking to Paul's comment:

You can generate a single file (.exe) with auto-py-to-exe, use the --one-file flag or in the GUI select One file

And don't stress to much about your code getting stealed.
